# iOS NearBy devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, core-location

Hi I am creating two apps where each app needs to know the location of the other app. I am using corelocation for that. However I am not sure whats the best/efficient way of getting the nearby devices. I can create a database with co-ordinates using parsi api. However I think that would be a lot of work to calculate the shortest distance every few minutes. Any ideas? I have a map for each app and i want to display the shortest distance between the two users on the map.I am using google maps api for ios

Answer (score 0):

If they're close enough (~30 meters) you can use iBeacons.

What would work the best depends on your particular app's needs.

**Edit**: Since you said your distance is too far, iBeacons won't work.

The brute-force way to do this is to run through all connected devices and calculate the (Pythagorean) distance to each one, and select the ones that are within your distance threshold. That's very time-consuming however.

Instead you might want to have each device report some sort of region code for each location (State? County? Zip code?) as the location changes. You'd use geocoding to generate the region information. You could have the reporting devices do the geocoding themselves, so they are only responsible for updating location information for a single device and you don't bog down doing geocoding. You'd report lat/long and region information to the server as it changes, with a "choke" to only report changes on significant changes, or once per minute, whichever is LESS frequent. (I remember reading in the docs that you are only supposed to submit a small number of geocoding calls or you get locked out and/or your app gets rejected.)

You'd collect the data in a central server.

Then you could start by requesting other users that match your current region (and possibly nearby regions) and then do distance calculations only on that small subset of your data that matches the region code.

Comment: the radius would be atleast 5 miles. ibeacons wont work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @WayneEllery, iBeacons were a possible answer, depending on the requirements. Based on the response it's not viable, but it was one possible solution.

Comment: The OP didn't mention distance so it's your job to clarify distance first before posting an answer. Your answer is also low quality as it provides no information on how to use iBeacons. Your post is more suited to a comment than an answer

Comment: @WayneEllery do you have a solution?

Comment: @OmarHashmi I'm just reviewing the quality of answers and this answer was flagged due to it's low quality. Unfortunately my knowledge of ios dev is low. I would think you would need to keep track of the devices locations by sending the data to a server. Then on the server you could find devices that are within range

Comment: I think this answer should stay here as in the question the distance is not specified so if someone would stumble upon this Q&A later it can be useful. Also @WayneEllery, I'd refrain from saying that anything is anyone's job here on SO. At least I believe the only thing expected here is to contribute as you can.

Comment: @fejese It was a poor choice of words

Answer (score 0):

The API to calculate distance is pretty lightweight.  Internally you use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate distance including the curvature of the Earth.  From the iOS perspective though you simply do this:

```
    CLLocation* previousPoint = [self.allLocations objectAtIndex:i-1];
    CLLocation* currentPoint = [self.allLocations objectAtIndex:i];
    CLLocationDistance distanceFromPrevPoint = [previousPoint distanceFromLocation:currentPoint];
```

You can easily iterate over the other devices in the zone.  If you want to reduce the number of calculations, you could only calculate distances to devices in the same base latitude longitude (ignore minutes and seconds).

Comment: I know thats not the problem.The thing is i have multiple devices and they could be anywhere in united states so I dont want to do this calculation for the whole country. I want to break it down into maybe cities but I dont know how to determine whether this device is in certain area or not without going through the whole database. I need to do it every few second so thats a lot of work. hard coding is also not a good idea.

Comment: Haversine is overkill for distances of a few km. For that you can simply use pythagorean distance (after calculating the distance for a degree of longitude at the current latitude.) You really only need Haversine when you are measuring distances where the curvature of the earth comes into play (multiple hundreds of km.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Parse, you should be able to do a `PFQuery` for all place objects within a given range. See the documentation here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#geo/iOS (Geo Queries)